# How to print out the final SQL statement in vertx?

Tags: sql, vert.x

I'm wondering how to print out the final SQL statement in `vertx`? It would be much easier to debug when we see the SQL statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x itself does not provide a way to log SQL statements. But:

- many JDBC drivers have options for logging statements
- in case your driver hasn't, tools like [p6spy](https://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/) let you intercept and log database activity